# Insert another slide between a pause in beamer

Tags: beamer, pause

I would like to have in beamer something like

```
\begin{frame}
The two main reasons are : 
\begin{itemize}
\item First reason
\pause 
\item Second reason
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

But I would like to insert an image to illustrate the first reason, that would be on another slide, without altering the display of my presentation.

I would therefore like to have

- Slide n : slide *a* with first item shown
- Slide n+1 : slide *b* with an image to illustrate this first item
- Slide n+2 : slide *a* with the two items displayed

How would it be possible ? And additionnaly would it be possible for the slide *b* not to be numbered ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<1>[label=blub]
    The two main reasons are : 
    \begin{itemize}
        \item First reason
        \pause 
        \item Second reason
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
    picture
\end{frame}

\againframe<2>{blub}

\end{document}
```